# InvalidBSON consumes cursor and raises StopIteration. How to skip over the bad document?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I am cursoring through a collection with some bad datetime data in one of the collection's documents.

```
mongo_query = {}
mongo_projection = {"createdAt": True} # many more date columns ommitted here
mongo_cursor = collection.find(mongo_query,
                               projection=mongo_projection
                               no_cursor_timeout=True)
```

Iterating over the cursor documents:

```
for i in range(100):
    try:
        mongo_cursor.next()
    except InvalidBSON:
        pass
```

I would expect the iterator to continue after the InvalidBSON error is handled but after the error, `.__next__()` raises a `StopIteration` error and there are no more documents left in the cursor.

I have tried accessing the documents with `for doc in mongo_cursor()` as well as converting to a list `list(mongo_cursor())` but everything fails in a similar way.

Is there a way of skipping over the bad data in a cursor in pymongo? Or is there a better way of handling this?

Comment: You might try using the query `mongo_query={"createdAt":{"$type":"date"}}` so the cursor only returns documents that have a proper date in that field.

Comment: @Joe The dates appear fine in mongo, it's an issue caused by pymongo trying to convert them into `datetime.datetime` (a python native library) that trips the error

Comment: I would print the _id of each document, and try to determine which one would come next when an error occurs.  Then figure out why pymongo can't translate the document.

Comment: `StopIteration` should be raised if you call `next` on the cursor when there are no more documents.  The response from the servers should be in BSON, so if the client side is getting `InvalidBSON` there is a bigger problem.   Have you tried iterating the cursor directly, like `for document in cursor:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pymongo will stop the iteration when it encounters invalid BSON. Ideally you should tidy up your invalid records rather than working around it; but maybe you don't know which are invalid?

The code below will work as stop-gap. Rather than get the full record, get just the `_id`, then do a `find_one()` on the record; you can put this in a `try...except` to flush out the invalid records.

As an aside, you can easily reproduce an InvalidBSON error in pymongo (for testing!!) by adding a date prior to the year 0001 **using the Mongo shell**:

```
db.mycollection.insertOne({'createdAt': new Date(-10000000000000)}) // valid in pymongo
db.mycollection.insertOne({'createdAt': new Date(-100000000000000)}) // **Not** valid in pymongo
db.mycollection.insertOne({'createdAt': new Date(-100000000)}) // valid in pymongo
```

pymongo code:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.errors import InvalidBSON

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
collection = db['mycollection']

mongo_query = {}
mongo_date_projection = {"createdAt": True} # many more date columns ommitted here
mongo_projection = {"_id": 1} # many more date columns ommitted here
mongo_cursor = collection.find(mongo_query,
                               projection=mongo_projection,
                               no_cursor_timeout=True)

for record in mongo_cursor:
    record_id = record.get('_id')
    try:
        item = collection.find_one({'_id': record_id}, mongo_date_projection)
        print(item)
    except InvalidBSON:
        print(f'Record with id {record_id} contains invalid BSON')
```

gives an output similar to:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5e6e1811c7c616e1ac58cbb3'), 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(1653, 2, 10, 6, 13, 20)}
Record with id 5e6e1818c7c616e1ac58cbb4 contains invalid BSON
{'_id': ObjectId('5e6e1a73c7c616e1ac58cbb5'), 'createdAt': datetime.datetime(1969, 12, 31, 23, 43, 20)}
```

Comment: What if you can't modify the existing data, only allowed to read the data?

Comment: FYI, `InvalidBSON` has moved to `bson.errors`.