# InvalidBSON Error - year 0 is out of range in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bson

I  am extracting data from Mongo  store using **python and pymongo** module.

I have tried using python 3.6,3.7 and also 3.9 versions. I have the same error in all the versions.

When the docs are returned by the cursor , we are getting the error as below.

```
      File "controller.py", line 86, in main
    data=extract_data()
  File "/apps/demo/extractdata.py", line 92, in extract_data
    for doc in docs:
  File "/apps/py37-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1156, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/apps/py37-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1093, in _refresh
    self.__send_message(g)
  File "/apps/py37-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 955, in __send_message
    address=self.__address)
  File "/apps/py37-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1346, in _run_operation_with_response
    exhaust=exhaust)
  File "/apps/py37-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1464, in _retryable_read
    return func(session, server, sock_info, slave_ok)
  File "/apps/py37-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1340, in _cmd
    unpack_res)
  File "/apps/py37-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/server.py", line 131, in run_operation_with_response
    user_fields=user_fields)
  File "/apps/py37-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1030, in _unpack_response
    legacy_response)
  File "/apps/py37-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/message.py", line 1591, in unpack_response
    self.payload_document, codec_options, user_fields)
  File "/apps/py37-venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bson/__init__.py", line 1098, in _decode_all_selective
    return decode_all(data, codec_options)

bson.errors.InvalidBSON: year 0 is out of range
```

I have validated the date related fields in  docs of mongo collection and we find them all to be correct. So, there  is no invalid date time  field value in the docs.

Also, I have even tried different approaches like skipping date related fields from collection while  extracting , so i feel it  is not due to date values in the collection. Perhaps, due to some misconfiguration in pymongo or resource  constraints on the host machine.

I am fetching data as a batch of records. While  reading the data for a batch of docs, we see that error for a specific document.

When  I fetch the specific document directly by passing the **'_id'** field using pymongo find query, it returns without error.

We are not sure if it is due python/pymongo are due to some resource constraints on the host machine like memory.

If someone has faced a similar issue can you please provide your suggestions on how to address this issue.

Comment: good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53177590/iterating-through-pymongo-cursor-throws-invalidbson-year-is-out-of-range

Comment: I have tried all options  as mentioned in the link you shared but I do  not see  any offending date field in the docs in collection.  Also, I have  tried excluding the date fields by adding the date query too. But, still have the same issue.

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60675503/invalidbson-consumes-cursor-and-raises-stopiteration-how-to-skip-over-the-bad-d for a mechanism to find the problem record(s)